# Firefox and IE are fast but Chrome and Vivaldi are slow

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, firefox

On my new Chuwi Lapbook 15.6 (Intel Cherry Trail Z8300 Quad Core 1.44GHz, 4GB RAM and Windows 10 x64), Firefox and Edge load and scroll quite fast but Google Chrome and Vivaldi take 1-2 secs to scroll on demanding pages such us Facebook and outlook.com. Both browsers are x64 version and both are using ~25-30% CPU on scrolling, but with Chrome and Vivaldi experience suffering. I could just start using Firefox/Edge but I need the sync feature of Chrome. Maybe something is wrong with graphics rendering? Something else? How to solve it?

Comment: There are also other chrome variants, such as Vivaldi, UC Browser, etc. Does it happen on these browsers too? If yes, then its not a problem you can fix. If no, try to get a fresh chrome experience by clearing cache, profile, etc

Comment: Vivaldi also sucks. Firefox and Edge work perfectly. What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

The real problem with Chrome is that it is a RAM eater. We cannot also make a sync feature for Firefox. But we can possibly speed up Chrome. Some ways to speed up Chrome could be found [here.](https://www.howtogeek.com/119191/browser-slow-how-to-make-google-chrome-fast-again/) Hope this help. :)

Comment: RAM usage seems usual, about 50% free. Disk usage also normal.